# How to get CentOS 8 option available as a VM option in GCP / GCE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, cloud, google-compute-engine

How would I go about getting **CentOS 8** as a VM option in GCP/GCE? or creating my own CentOS 8 VM to run on GCP?

Any guides (README's, documents) there or contacts on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on GCP that talks about a technique/recipe for creating a boot image that is custom.  The article is called [Manually importing virtual disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image).   If I understand the basics of the story, you could use a technology such as VirtualBox to create a local VM image and then prepare that for import into Google Cloud Storage.  From there, one could then seem to use that as a source for a new Compute Engine instance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently GCP supports Centos-7 as a public image. As suggested by the previous member you can create a Custom image from source disks, images, snapshots, or images stored in Cloud Storage.

See instructions [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#creating_a_custom_image)

Your other option is to wait for Google to introduce Centos-8 in their [supported family](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support)

Answer (score 0):

Centos 8 is already [available on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#unshielded-images) but it is without shielded VM support.